# Difference between two sql statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the difference between:

```
declare @GUIDs                      nvarchar(max) = @LoaIDs, 
        @AccountStatus              uniqueidentifier
```

and

```
declare @GUIDs                      nvarchar(max) = @LoaIDs
declare @AccountStatus              uniqueidentifier
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: More or less typing.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken the first option is applicable since ms sql 2008.

Comment: both are the same, just use what you like most and make it company policy so all developers use the same style

Comment: Only difference is that first one has `,` and it's declare within same declare while other is declaring each variable at the time and that's why has extra `declare` and no `,`

Comment: I genuinely wanted to know if there was something else going on here other than a declare.  I mean I guess the downvotes can be justified but what other forum can I ask this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Differences, Both cases Work as Same except that you are declaring them using 2 statements. But There are no performance effects

Comment: I think this should be a comment instead of answer